# Need all joomla pages <jdoc:include type="head" />  in header except home page

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

Need all joomla pages `<jdoc:include type="head" />` in header except home page , what is the solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Joomla 1.6, 1.7 and 2.5

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()):
?>

    <jdoc:include type="head" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

[Reference](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page).

Comment: hey, i dont want  <jdoc:include type="head" />  in home page, that was my question, but need this code in other all pages, thanks

Comment: That's exactly what the code does. The code says: if the current page is NOT the homepage, then include the `head`. In other words, `head` will not be included in the homepage, but on all other pages.

Comment: woow, Its working thanks, how to remove unwanted files from pages? i used to many plugins so many js files are included in all pages

Comment: @Hunter, consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick, if it solved your problem. Regarding unwanted files, that's unrelated to this question so I would suggest posting a new question specifically to that and provide more details. Also include your Joomla! version in future questions because solutions vary across different major versions.